# Javascript to remove alert() script in url before it executes

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP.  I'm attempting to prevent some XSS on my page.  One test I'm running has this in the url params:

```
www.mypage.com?error=<script>alert(11170579)</script>&foo=one&bar=two
```

The `errorr=...` param is not coming from a form input. It's just inserted into the url.

How can I use Javascript to escape/decode the  tags so the alert() does not execute?  I did find a couple of examples of parsing the param values in the url, but none mentioned how to prevent or change the code so it did not run.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I find OWASP is still a good resource for these topics: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet Be explicit, trust no one.

Comment: Please consult with a security expert for this rather than random strangers on the internet. It is clear from what you are asking that you don't understand the problem  you're attempting to solve sufficiently.

Comment: You're looking at the problem from entirely the wrong angle.  The solution is not to *safely* execute the code (by "escaping" undesirable things), the solution is to *not execute user input as code in the first place*.  No web browser will, by default, execute JavaScript code typed into the URL like that.  *You* are doing that.  Don't do it.

Comment: first of all you shall not put script as a parameter...

Comment: @singebatteur — How is he supposed to test his defences against XSS without doing that?

Comment: oh yeah just testing my bad

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP's [htmlspecialchars](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function. This seems to be what you want:

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['error']);
?>
```